# Snappy webchat example not working

Tags: nodejs, ubuntu-core, snap

I am new in snappy ubuntu core.
I downloaded the webchat example from https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/tree/master/examples/webchat. Then I called snapcraft snap command, and snappy build inside snap folder.
That created .snap file which I copied to my Beagle bone black and installed it successfully. I followed all instructions but application, when I go to http://webdm.local:3000  in my browser, is not working. Did I forget something, and what I need to do to make this example work on BeagleBone Black? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Snapcraft are you using? Which version of Ubuntu Core are you using? Also, can you be more specific about HOW it's not working? Finally, any errors in the syslog?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu core 15.4 and Snapcraft version 1.1.0. on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. There are no errors in syslog but there is no service in etc/systemd/system to start the application either.  I can maually change package.yaml file like in on this link https://insights.ubuntu.com/2015/06/03/so-you-want-to-write-a-snappy-app/ but then some paths are not right and application doesn't start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using examples out of the master branch of Snapcraft, which represents Snapcraft 2.x. Since you're using Snapcraft 1.x, I suggest either using the example [here](https://github.com/ubuntu-core/snapcraft/tree/1.x/examples/webchat), or use the examples distributed for your Snapcraft release with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install snapcraft-examples
```

Those examples should work a bit more like what you expect :) .

Comment: Thank you Kyle. I didn't see that branch is set on master. But now I have a problem after I build it with right snapcraft yaml script. Linux service is failed when it's automatically called. To check why it's not working I opened webchat_server_IOgafUPRUCPP.service and in other terminal gone to WorkingDirectory. So when i run ExecStart line from service it should work but it's doesn't.  I says "/apps/webchat.sideload/IOgafUPRUCPP/bin/webchat-for-a-snap.wrapper: 5: exec: /bin/webchat-for-a-snap: not found
"

Comment: and when I start service with systemctl I get error  Active: failed (Result: start-limit) and (code=exited, status=2)

Comment: Anything in the syslog?

Comment: I got new info about problem. I repeated the whole procedure with KVM and everything works fine. So it is problem with BeagleBone Black. Maybe it is beacause I create .snap package on x64 and beagle is x32.

Comment: Ah, yes indeed-- Snapcraft doesn't support cross-building, so you need to build on the same architecture.

Comment: Do you know will it work if I download node packages that are supported by armhf arhitecture and replace original ones in snap folder after snapcraft snap command??